# Realurl generating unwanted language codes inside url

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, realurl

I'm again stuck up with a realurl trouble.. This time it's worse than ever. I've configured `realurl_conf` for L parameter as well as for other parameters.

```
'preVars' => 
    array (
      array(
        'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
        'valueMap' => array(
          'nc' => 1,
      ),
      'noMatch' => 'bypass',
    ),
      array (
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'valueMap' => array (
          'en'      => '0',     // Default
          'it'      => '5',     // Italian
          'de'      => '7',     // German
        ),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
      ),
    ),
```

URLs are generating perfectly as expected.. But for some pages the urls are being shown like

```
mydomain.ch/de/nr/page1/innerpage
```

innerpage's typoScript template is like,

```
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1

# language configuration
page.config.linkVars = L
page.config.sys_language_uid = 7
page.config.language = de
page.config.locale_all = de_DE.utf8
page.config.htmlTag_langKey = de

# english language
[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
page.config.sys_language_uid = 0
page.config.language = en
page.config.locale_all = en_GB.utf8
page.config.htmlTag_langKey = en
[global]
```

Any one have any idea, what is happening? (The confusing part is like 'nr' is not even configured anywhere!)

Answer (score 0):

OMG !!! Some how alternative page title was there for a page which is 'nr'. That is shown in url. Wasted around 2 hours, checking other configurations. So.. Next time, honestly guyz.. Check page properties. 
Slipped this time. (y)